# ArrayList contains not detecting what it should

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an `arrayList` with a bunch of strings in it. I also have another `arrayList` with a bunch of strings. I would like to see whether the first array list contains any string from the second arrayList and if so, just to print it out. Should be simple but it doesn't seems to work (and there are definitely strings in common).

Here is my code:

```
 ArrayList<String> che=new ArrayList<String>();
 for (int i = 1; i <= rsmd.getColumnCount(); i++) {
     System.out.println("COL"+rsmd.getColumnName(i));
     che.add(rsmd.getColumnName(i).trim());
 }
 String key = "";
 String keys = "";
 for (Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
     key = entry.getKey().replace(":","")
           .replace(">","MoreThan").replace("__","")
           .replaceAll("\\." ,"").replaceAll("\\(s\\)" ,"")
           .replaceAll(",$" ,"").replaceAll("%" ,"")
           .replaceAll("\\(" ,"").replaceAll("\\)" ,"")
           .replace("-" ,"").replace("-" ,"")
           .replace("_" ,"").replace("#" ,"")
           .replaceAll("\\/", "_").replaceAll("@", "AT")
           .replaceAll("&", "AND").replaceAll("\\?", "AND")
           .replace("≤","LessThan").replace("≥","MoreThan")
           .replaceAll("\\s" ,"").replaceAll("^,","");  
     for (String n:che){
         System.out.println("Che_String "+n);
         System.out.println("KEY_String "+key);
         if (n==key){
             System.out.println("Detected the same: "+key.trim());
         }
     }
 }
```

I know there are a lot of replaces and I should use `StringUtils.repaceEach` and I will do so but need to sort this first

The `System.out.println` output shows that there are several similar strings but they are not being picked up eg

```
Che_String Gender
KEY_String Gender
```

But my `Detected the same:` output is empty.

I've also tried `che.contains(key)` with the same results.

Comment: Use `equals` to compare `String`s, not `==`.

Comment: `==` merely compares references, not the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String should be compared with the `String.equals(String)` method. With `==` you compare if it is the same object and not the same content. `List.contains(Object)` is using the `equals()` method. So this should work. Maybe you got some whitespace at the end of your text that is not visible in your test print.

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8:

`che.stream().filter(n -> map.keySet().contains(n)).forEach(match -> System.out.println("Detected the same: " + match);)`